# Loading all documents from ElasticSearch takes too long

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

In order to load all the documents index by ElasticSearch, I am using the following query through tire.

```
  def all
    max = total
    Tire.search 'my_documents' do
      query { all }
      size max
    end.results.map { |entry| entry.to_hash }
  end
```

Where `max`, respectively `total` is a count query to return the number of present documents. I have indexed about 10,000 documents. Currently, the request takes too long.

I am aware, that I should not query all documents like this. What is the best alternative here? Using pagination, if yes, toward which metric would I define the number of documents per page?

I am also planning to extend the size of the documents, to 100,000 or even 1,000,000 and I don't see yet how this can scale.

I appreciate every comment.

---

Rationale: I do this, because I am running calculations over these data. Hence, I need all the data, run the computations and save the results back into the documents.

Comment: You might want to expand your rationale with the type of calculations, and specifically whether these are per-document or aggregated. Elastic Search *may* be able to do some of these calculations on the server, which would be more efficient than a client-based retrieve/calculate/update script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the scroll API, which is highly optimized to fetch a large amount of results. It uses the scan search type and doesn't support sorting but let you provide a query to filter the documents you want to fetch. Have a look at the [reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/scroll/) to know more about it. Remember the size that you define in the request is per shard; that means that if you have 5 primary shards, setting 10 would lead to have 50 results back per request.